# Assign keystonejs callback function data to array

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I'm new to node.js and currently working on a project using keystonejs cms and MongoDB. Now I'm stuck in getting data related to multiple collections. Because of this callback functions, I couldn't return an array with relational data. My code something similar to this sample code.

```
var getAgenda = function(id, callback){
callback = callback || function(){};
if(id){

    AgendaDay.model.find({summit:id}).exec(function (err, results3) {

        var arr_agenda = [];
        var arr_agenda_item = [];   

        for(var key3 in results3){                
            AgendaItem.model.find({agendaDay:results3[key3]._id}).exec(function  (err, results2){

                for(var key2 in results2){                        

                    arr_agenda_item.push(
                    {
                            item_id: results2[key2]._id, 
                            item_name: results2[key2].name,
                            from_time: results2[key2].time_from,   
                            to_time: results2[key2].time_to,   
                            desc: results2[key2].description, 
                            fatured: results2[key2].featured,     
                        }
                    ); 
                }   
                arr_agenda.push(
                {
                        name: results3[key3].name, 
                        date: results3[key3].date, 
                        description: results3[key3].description,
                        item_list:arr_agenda_item    
                    }
                ); 

                return callback(arr_agenda);

            });
        }
    });
  }
}

exports.list = function (req, res) {

var mainarray = [];

Summit.model.find().exec(function (err, resultssummit) {
    if (err) return res.json({ err: err });
    if (!resultssummit) return res.json('not found');

    Guest.model.find().exec(function (err, resultsguset) {

        for(var key in resultssummit){  

            var agen_arr = [];  

            for(var i=0; i<resultssummit[key].guests.length; i++){      

                var sumid = resultssummit[key]._id;

                    //this is the function im trying get data and assign to mainarray
                    getAgenda(sumid, function(arr_agenda){                  
                        agen_arr = arr_agenda;
                    });

                    mainarray.push(
                        {
                            id: resultssummit[key]._id, 
                            name: resultssummit[key].name,
                            agenda_data: agen_arr,
                        }
                    );
            }

            res.json({
                summit: mainarray,
            }); 
        }       

    });

  }
}
```

If anyone can help me out, that would be really great :)

Comment: I see issues in both functions. Which one do you want help in? They dont even look connected.

Comment: You just need to put the `mainarray.push` code inside the `getAgenda` callback.

Comment: @DushyantBangal i'm sorry i have updated the question :) 
yeah I have tried putting mainarray.push inside the getAgenda but then I have got an empty array out side of callback function. I need to get agen_arr out side of the getAgenda callback, is there any way to do that?

Comment: The only way is to execute depends on `agen_arr` inside the `getAgenda` callback. For a clean code, you can put all of it in a function, and then give it as the callback

Comment: You need to restructure this whole thing. You should not be calling mongo queries in a for loop and expecting their output at the end of the loop. Also, your response is in a for loop. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure this whole thing. You should not be calling mongo queries in a for loop and expecting their output at the end of the loop. Also, your response is in a for loop. That won't work.

I'll tell you how to do it. I cannot refactor all of that code for you.

Instead of putting mongodb queries in a for loop, you need to convert it in a single query. Just put the `_id`s in a single array and fire a single query.

```
AgendaItem.model.find({agendaDay:{$in:ARRAY_OF_IDS}})
```

You need to do the same thing for `AgendaDay.model.find({summit:id})` as well.